# d3.js using functions within d3.js-specific functions

Tags: javascript, function, d3.js, visualization

I was wondering if it is possible to use functions within d3.js functions. 
To clarify my question, let's assume you have a colorscale

```
  var colorScale = d3.scale.quantile()
                .domain([0,8])
                .range(["#ffffd9","#edf8b1","#c7e9b4","#7fcdbb","#41b6c4","#1d91c0","#225ea8","#253494","#081d58"]);
```

Is there a way to make the following work?

```
      var colorScale = d3.scale.quantile()
            .domain([0,8])
            .range(function(){return ["#ffffd9","#edf8b1","#c7e9b4","#7fcdbb","#41b6c4","#1d91c0","#225ea8","#253494","#081d58"]});
```

so returning the entire argument from a function?

many thanks to anyone who knows!

Comment: can you clarify your goals? In the example you gave it makes more sense to simply use your own function directly instead of a D3 scale

Comment: This question is answered in the [API documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#quantile_range).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you Explunit, Lars and Thomas

I have found an adequate answer to my question though.

The answer is: yes it's possible and here is how if you know the argument to your range is going to be a function:

```
var myfunction = function()
        {return ["#ffffd9","#edf8b1","#c7e9b4","#7fcdbb","#41b6c4","#1d91c0","#225ea8","#253494","#081d58"]}   

        var colorScale = d3.scale.quantile()
                .domain([0,8])
                .range(myfunction());
```

If however you are not sure. you can use the d3.functor() which will work even if you pass it a value and not a function. So like this (if it's a function):

```
 var myfunction = function()
        {return ["#ffffd9","#edf8b1","#c7e9b4","#7fcdbb","#41b6c4","#1d91c0","#225ea8","#253494","#081d58"]}

        var myfunctionWrapped =  d3.functor(myfunction);

        var colorScale = d3.scale.quantile()
                .domain([0,8])
                .range(myfunctionWrapped());
```

And like this if it is a value (or array):

```
var myfunction = ["#ffffd9","#edf8b1","#c7e9b4","#7fcdbb","#41b6c4","#1d91c0","#225ea8","#253494","#081d58"]

var myfunctionWrapped =  d3.functor(myfunction);

var colorScale = d3.scale.quantile()
        .domain([0,8])
        .range(myfunctionWrapped());
```

So I would recommend using the d3.functor() since it makes your code more versatile.

Answer (score 1):

Not with ranges. Although many other d3 methods allow functions as parameters. Those are generally methods which are likely to return different values based on a specific datum.